# How do I make two independent drop down lists that don't interact with eachother?

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu

This is the code I got so far and I woul'd like to make two speperate lists, one for the difficulty and one for the characters. But if I change the variable in one list the otherlist changes too. I cant find anything on youtube or forums that explain how to make them independant from eachother.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
import pygame

root= tk.Tk()

root.title("Generic Game")
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 300, bg="black")
canvas1.pack()
canvas1.create_text(150,50, text="Square attak 2: The Devil returns", font="Times", fill="white")
root.resizable(False, False)



def startEasy():
  print("Game started")

def startgame():
  if variable.get() == DifficultyList[1]:
    startEasy()
  elif variable.get() == DifficultyList[2]:
    messagebox.showinfo("Info", "You are now not playing on Medium mode!")
  elif variable.get() == DifficultyList[3]:
    messagebox.showinfo("Info", "You are now not playing on Hard mode!")
  else:
    messagebox.showinfo("Disclaimer", "You need to choose a difficulty!")


startbutton = tk.Button(root, text="Start", command=startgame, fg="black", activeforeground="white", activebackground ="green").place(x=96, y=150)

exitbutton = tk.Button(root, text="Exit Game", command=root.destroy, fg="black", activebackground="red").place(x=96, y=250)

canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=exitbutton)
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=startbutton)


DifficultyList = [
"Difficulty",
"Easy",
"Medium",
"Hard"
]


Characters = [
  "Harold",
  "Stefan",
  "Peter"
]


variable = tk.StringVar(root)

variable.set(DifficultyList[0])
variable.set(Characters[0])

Difficulty = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *DifficultyList).place(x=96, y=100)  
Characters = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *Characters).place(x=10, y=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: give a different control variable to Characters (change `tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *Characters)` change that variable to something else)

Comment: could you give and example I don't really know what you mean

Comment: I think I figured it out now, thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: you see this `variable = tk.StringVar()`. Make a similar variable say `char_var =  tk.StringVar()` now change `Characters = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *Characters).place(x=10, y=10)` -> `Characters = tk.OptionMenu(root, char_var, *Characters).place(x=10, y=10)` also change `variable.set(Characters[0])` to `char_var.set(Characters[0])`. Note Your `Characters` is `None` since `place` returns `None` and don't assign optionmenu to the same variable as the list.

Comment: Yes thats what I did after some thought on your first answer but thank you anyway :)

Comment: `OptionMenu` are quite old, use `ttk.Combobox` for more flexibility.

Comment: This is just a small school project that don't have to be finished all the way through. But in the future I'll use something newer and better for the next time I code.

Answer (score 0):

give a different control variable to Characters (change tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *Characters) change that variable to something else) – JacksonPro

you see this:
variable = tk.StringVar().
Make a similar variable say:
char_var =  tk.StringVar()
now change Characters = tk.OptionMenu(root, variable, *Characters).place(x=10, y=10) -> Characters = tk.OptionMenu(root, char_var, *Characters).place(x=10, y=10) also change variable.set(Characters[0]) to char_var.set(Characters[0]).
Note Your Characters is None since place returns None and don't assign optionmenu to the same variable as the list. – JacksonPro

Comment: pls, consider writing a [good answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) instead of simply pasting my comment here as an answer.